# Find exact substring in cell using excel formula

Tags: excel, string, search, substring, contains

I have the string "L5+L6+L7+L10" in a cell, and then I have a column with the values L1, L2, ... , L10 on each cell. I need to know which of those values are contained in the main string but with an exact match.

To solve my problem, I tried the formula `=IF(ISNUM(SEARCH(B3;$F$2));"Found";"Not found")` and the results I get are shown in this image.

[image]

However, this results are incorrect because I need only L5, L6, L7 and L10 to be found, and not L1.

Is there a way to do so only using excel formulas?

Comment: Are you open to a VBA `UDF` solution?

Comment: @urdearboy I'm afraid I'm trying to avoid using VBA as much as possible.

Comment: If you have any control over the format of `Substring`, this would work with `L01` instead of `L1`. Interested in this one. I cannot think of a way to do this as is with formulas. Thought substitute might work but no. Where you at Ben & Scott!

Comment: I tried `=IF(LEN($F$2)=LEN(SUBSTITUTE($F$2,B3,"")),"Not Found","Found")` but have the same issue with **partial matching** as you do.

Comment: @urdearboy as a temporary solution I'm modifying the format of `Search string` so it contains "L5 + L6 + L7 + L10 " (with white spaces). It allows me to use the `"*"` wildcard in my formula. However, I'm not sure if I can actually modify the format so this is not the final solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `"+"` to the beginning and end of the strings inside the search:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("+"&B3&"+","+"&$F$3&"+")),"Found","Not found")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `FILTERXML` function can help in this case:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B3=FILTERXML("<data><a>" & SUBSTITUTE($F$2;"+";"</a><a>") & "</a></data>";"//a")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The other one is simpler and shorter but yours work as well

Answer (score 0):

### For anyone viewing question & open to VBA `UDF` solution

Post code into a worksheet module

Syntax of formula: `=Found( Substring, Search String )`

So on the excel sheet: `C3 = Found(B3, F2) = Not Found`

---

```
Public Function Found(SubString As Range, Within As Range) As String

Dim Arr, i As Long
Arr = Split(Within, "+")

Found = "Not Found"

For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    If SubString = Arr(i) Then
        Found = "Found"
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

End Function
```